wood frame, corner joints and braces
I'm building an outside enclosure for my cats. I've done that before using pocket holes and lots of screws. I've since added a router to my tools collection and was wondering if it's a good idea to do it without screws, with joints and braces, similar to this picture:

Those particular joints and braces may not be ideal. I've searched a bit but couldn't find what specific joints I should be using on both the corner and the 45° bits. That are a) relatively stable and b) possible for a relative beginner to do. It doesn't have to be elegant, I don't think the cats care much. :-)
The construction needs to be sturdy enough to take the weight of 2 cats jumping on it (each one being about 5kg) plus whatever platforms, ladders, walkways, etc. I decide to add.
Or maybe that's a stupid idea and I should do it with pocket holes and screws again?
Context:
My final frame would look like an 8 - 200cm x 100cm with a third horizontal part in the middle for stability and to fix platforms and stuff for the cats to jump on. There would be several such segments connecting together for the enclosure. Mesh on the outside, done.

You can build with screws (standard construction for decks) with glue and screws (standard construction for some types of utilitarian stuff) and with joinery, with or without glue (everything from construction to fine furniture). It's entirely up to you which route you take. As an experienced SEer you know subjective Qs are specifically called out as not being a good fit for the Q&A model here.

I've upvoted the Q since it's clear you did some research, but still VTC :-)

@Graphus I know that I can build in multiple ways. I've looked at a couple of possible joints. What I have absolutely no idea about and can't understand from the youtube and blogs is a) is this a good idea or are pocket holes objectively better (more stable, easier, etc.) and b) which joint is something I as a relative beginner won't regret trying?

"What I have absolutely no idea about and can't understand from the youtube and blogs is a) is this a good idea or are pocket holes objectively better (more stable, easier, etc.) and b) which joint is something I as a relative beginner won't regret trying?" Well a) is actually discoverable in the research required by SE prior to asking a Q (it doesn't even need to be that in-depth as comparisons between pocket-hole screws and other options abound online), and b) this is also highly subjective — it's completely down to the beginner, each one being different in what they can grok, achieve.

This is really fully covered by my first Comment but let me bottom-line it for you. You can build using just screws and no glue (remember there are other ways to screw than just using pocket-hole screws, although where the latter is available use 'em where useful) and achieve a perfectly sound, stable and long-lasting structure. You can go entirely the other direction, go full-on with joinery that has no glue (pegged/pinned, wedged) and get the same. Multiple routes in between, ditto. So it's not about whether one construction option is better than another (by whatever metric one chooses).

@Graphus Right. I honestly thought this would be a relatively easy question and someone would be able to say "x is better because and the Y type is the easiest beginner joints for this purpose". I didn't think it's so subjective.

There are often no objectively better options, it's all about a balance of tooling, experience, the amount of effort one feels like expending, and just plain personal preference. If you take just one element of one piece as an example — the front rail on a workbench table, that can be attached to the legs as an overlap joint, halving joints (lap joints), M&T joints of at least 3 kinds, lag screws, pocket-hole screws, bolt and nut (conventional and dowel nut). And others I'm probably not thinking of at the moment. There is literally nothing but personal preference to choose between them.....

...as workbenches have been built using all of the above (and more); and depending a little on on use-case every one will stand the test of time. You can extrapolate from that to the attachment of the diagonal brace here, on either or both ends. If it is merely a matter of personal preference how you do it, and it is, as the possibilities include many (if not effectively all alternatives, since it includes arguably the most basic, butt joints) and yet still yield acceptable strength and longevity, then by definition it's a matter of opinion.

Agree that this is an opinion-heavy question, but here's my opinion. Pocket screws, glue, lap joints (ie, no fancy joinery), and fancy joinery will all get the job done. The reason to do fancy stuff (as pictured) is to learn, build a router jig for mortising, and generally have fun making sawdust. So to your first question, "is it a good idea"? Yes, if you have the time and inclination.

A ps about mortising with a router... I wouldn't. The jig will take so much time to build that you'd be done 10 units with a chisel and a hand-held drill in the same time as you did one with a router.

And, as long as we're throwing around some opinions: Don't use pocket screws. They're excellent for some applications, but this isn't necessarily one of them. As things rack and flex, expand and contract, pocket screws will loosen up. I think your original idea is worth pursuing. You'll learn a lot and feel more satisfaction without the pocket screws.
